# How do I execute two methods using onClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to create a simple weather app using OpenWeatherMap API. I am using OkHttp library to perform a GET request. All it does is take an input throught `EditText` and update the `TextView` on button click using a `Button`.

But the problem is, the `TextView` updates after two clicks on the `Button`. I want to update it right after the first click. So, how do I go over this?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText cityName;
    private TextView weatherData;
    private TextView hiddenText;
    private Button getBtn;
    public String s = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        weatherData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
        getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getData);
        cityName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cityName);

        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getWeatherData(cityName.getText().toString());
                weatherData.setText(s);
            }
        });

    }


    public void getWeatherData(String cityText){

        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityText + "&appid=ba45ceb57328448f7wd666hdc6d57aaf";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        s = "Something went wrong!";
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                s = response.body().string();
                            }
                            catch (IOException ioe){
                                s = "Error while getting JSON.";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know that I can update the `TextView` in `onResponse` itself but I wanna know if it is possible to update it through `onClickListener`. If it's not possible, which method should I use? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update text value in server response call back

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText cityName;
    private TextView weatherData;
    private TextView hiddenText;
    private Button getBtn;
    public String s = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        weatherData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
        getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getData);
        cityName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cityName);

        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getWeatherData(cityName.getText().toString());
                
            }
        });

    }


    public void getWeatherData(String cityText){

        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityText + "&appid=ba45ceb57328448f7wd666hdc6d57aaf";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        s = "Something went wrong!";
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                s = response.body().string();

                                weatherData.setText(s);
                            }
                            catch (IOException ioe){
                                s = "Error while getting JSON.";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I know how to do that, but I want to update it outside of that server response callback.

Comment: I did not understand what you said? I want to update the ```String s``` in response callback but want to update the ```TextView``` outside of it. I mean I want to update it in ```onClickListener``` or ```onFocusChange``` something like that.

Comment: you can not do this , because server response have some delay and setText() method did execute faster , so you have to wait for response  or you can update text in response callback like what is answer

Comment: Ohh! Now I get it. So, the app runs on threads right? That's what the reason that the TextView updates first and then response function will return json string to the app. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting data on edit text on click after calling GET Request.
Update the textview with the data , once you get the response.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private EditText cityName;
    private TextView weatherData;
    private TextView hiddenText;
    private Button getBtn;
    public String s = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        weatherData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
        getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getData);
        cityName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cityName);

        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getWeatherData(cityName.getText().toString());
               
            }
        });

    }


    public void getWeatherData(String cityText){

        String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityText + "&appid=ba45ceb57328448f7wd666hdc6d57aaf";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        s = "Something went wrong!";
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                s = response.body().string();
                                 weatherData.setText(s);
                            }
                            catch (IOException ioe){
                                s = "Error while getting JSON.";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to update it in server response function. I want to update it outside of it

Comment: You are saving in string s, in server response

Comment: yes, I want to save that server response into the string s. Then I want to update the TextView outside of the server response function. I mean I want to update it in onClickListener or onFocusChange functions.

Comment: you cant do that, GET request is an async operation. or you can create an interface

Comment: the guy above has less contribution score and he answered first. so, ill go with him. anyway, thank you for your answer!